# How to increase max length of line in VSCODE editor?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have an issue where my code-lines wrap to the next line too soon and there's a weird empty margin on the right side of my editor, which takes up useless space. I thought it was the minimap at first, but it's  not that. The size remains the same regardless of the editor window size.

I've probably added it by accident through some shortcut keys but can't find anything related to it from the settings.

[image]

Comment: If you hover on that line does the cursor change to allow you to drag it wider?

Comment: What extension are you using to format your code? Does this same line show up regardless of your programming language?

Comment: @easleyfixed nope, can't drag it, cursor doesn't change or react to it.

Comment: @Samathingamajig good catch, looks like it only happens with dart/flutter, but with a C# project it doesn't show up, so must be one of the extensions causing it. Didn't even think of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have the Dart extension installed. If so, change `Dart: Line Length` to a higher number (9999999 if you want). 0 might also work to disable that option.

[image]

As it says, you might also need to change the rulers in the dart section of settings.json

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgGxA.png)
Open Extensions on the menu on the left or File menu.

Then click on the extension settings button.

Change the line length for the extension you are working with.